# C++ program showing "Invalid initialization" error

Tags: visual-c++

My program is not compiling. It shows Invalid Initialization .
[c++ programming,initialization problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ljPv.png)

Comment: Your code belongs in the question as text. Your program is not compiling, that is different than not running.

Comment: Please add your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your array initialisation seems to be wrong. Arrays should be initialised like this:

```
int marks[5]={1,2,3};
```

Comment: Swarna, I don't want to be mean, but this was a simple bug that you could have fixed on your own. Next time , when you run into something like this, try to find a solution yourself. Use google or refer the material you are using to learn. You should post your questions to Stack Overflow only if you have tried everything and still couldn't figure it out. Also, whenever you are asking a question, try to include whatever you have tried to solve the issue. Visit the "How to ask a good question?" page for more info. Good luck and Happy coding :)